# Phrase Html Document for node font size

Tags: c#, html, font-face, html-agility-pack, phrase

Is there any way to phrase(read) the html node font size.

It is in C# and I try checking out the htmlagilitypack but can't find anything.

I am using C# to extract information from webpage and need to know what font/style it have.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This information is normally coming in CSS files... so it is unlikely to get it from HTML alone.

Comment: For example Inspect tag in chrome show the font info. how they get it?

Comment: I.e. [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle) when you have real element nodes in browser. HtmlAgilityPack does not provide such ability as far as I know. You would still need all CSS in correct resolution of the page to correctly get styles.